# I want to know how API functions work. where can i find its implementation code?

Tags: webots

Brain box. I work in Linux with C language. I want to know how API functions work. For example,wb_radar_get_number_of_targets(WbDeviceTag tag), how can I find its implementation code, that is, its. C code

Comment: A search for "Webots" quickly reveals [its source code](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/blob/565b5aed95a2aadb73bccf2ad733d37893d5edfe/src/lib/Controller/api/radar.c#L170).

Answer (score 0):

I would first recommend following the Webots tutorials, in particular, the one about controllers:
https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/tutorial-4-more-about-controllers

Then you will find the description of the radar C API here:
https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/radar#radar-functions

Finally, you can find the implementation of the radar C API here:
https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/blob/master/src/lib/Controller/api/radar.c

And the Webots side:
https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/blob/master/src/webots/nodes/WbRadar.cpp